# Running Java Applet

Tags: java, applet

I have not been able to run a java applet from [this](https://www.grc.nasa.gov/WWW/K-12/rocket/ienzl.html) link. I tried reinstalling java multiple times and running it in internet explorer but it doesn't seem to work. I was just wondering if there is something simple I am skipping over, or perhaps a different way of running it that I have not yet tried?

Comment: Java applets have been deprecated for a long time.  Virtually no browsers support them (except IE11 or earlier), and modern JREs no longer support them (Java 9 or higher).  Your best bet is to install an OLDER JRE (Java 7 or 8) and use IE11.

Comment: I'm not sure this really qualifies as a programming question. Seems more like a sysadmin problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to run the applet with the "Applet Runner" plug-in: https://www.japplis.com/applet-runner/

Running it from the url didn't work because of some weird redirect, so I've downloaded it using the "Download Applet" button and was able to run it using the Rnoz.html file in the zip file.

Note that I'm the developer of *Applet Runner*.

Answer (score -1):

Leaning Technologies provides CheerpJ Applet Runner: a free (for non commercial use) Chrome extension to safely run applets on Chrome: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cheerpj-applet-runner/bbmolahhldcbngedljfadjlognfaaein

If you need support for other browser or in a commercial/enterprise settings, please take a look here for all the information about the CheerpJ technology: https://leaningtech.com/cheerpj

Full disclosure: I am CTO of Leaning Technologies

Answer (score -2):

Did you try running it in an IDE? If not, download Eclipse(A Java IDE) [here](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/). There is a tutorial for running Java Applets [here](http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/%7Ekaharris/10200/tutorials/eclipse/applet.html).